`node_modules` is present warning with pnpm
When I run pnpm install in my project I get a warning:
`node_modules` is present. Lockfile only installation will make it out-of-date

What will be out of date. node_modules the lockfile? Should I be concered about this> How can I fix this.
I am using pnpm version 9.11 with pnpm workspaces.

What Will Be Out of Date?

node_modules: May not match the state described in pnpm-lock.yaml.
pnpm-lock.yaml: May not reflect changes in node_modules.

Should I Be concerned about this?
Yes, if you need consistency between node_modules and pnpm-lock.yaml, especially in workspaces or deployments.

How can I Fix This?

Proper Installation: Run:
pnpm i


Clear and Reinstall:
rm -rf node_modules
pnpm i


Validate Lockfile:
rm -rf node_modules pnpm-lock.yaml
pnpm i


Check Workspace Configs: Ensure pnpm-workspace.yaml and lockfile are up to date, then run:
pnpm i




I think If node_modules is not aligned with the pnpm-lock.yaml file, the warning means it won't update the node_modules folder to match the lockfile during this "lockfile-only" installation.
The lockfile (pnpm-lock.yaml) itself will remain unchanged.
Make sure that node_modules matches the pnpm-lock.yaml file and the dependencies declared in your workspace.
if not delete and re install it again
# Clean up and reinstall to fix the issue
`rm -rf node_modules
pnpm i --force`

